# MySQL Insertions continuing after the script has been closed

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a script which populates my SQL database with categories from ebay, it sends and recieves xml requests and inserts the data into the database as needed. Since eBay takes a few seconds per request to respond, I had to extend the script's maximum execution time.

After closing the script to change it, the insertions continued, and still are continuing, over 10k entries about now, is there anyway of stopping the database from accepting or processing any more requests from that table? or do I have to wait until it finally stops however long that may be?

Comment: Who does those inserts? Find and kill it. Or you could shutdown whole DB server. This will certainly stop the inserts :)

Comment: the inserts were from the script i was running, that is now closed, but I can't shut down the DB since other tables, that are perfectly fine, are being used.

Comment: Well, inserts can't appear out of nowhere. Something must be issuing them.

Comment: What means "closed"? How did you stop the execution of the program?

Comment: stopped it loading and closed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you request a page, and then close a window, it doesn't cause the page to stop executing.

It will continue to execute until it completes, times out or gets forcefully terminated.

I suspect you have gone a little overboard with your timeout, so increase it more gradually!